# How can I resolve these running warnings for python code?

Tags: python, debugging

```
import numpy as np #code 1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Return(N):
    A=np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if j==i:
                A[i,j]=4
            else:
                if j>i+2:
                    A[i,j]=0
                else:
                    A[i,j]=-1
    for i in range (2,N,+1):
        for j in range(0,i-2):
            A[i,j]=0
    A[N-1,N-1]=3
    A[0,0]=3 
    return A
def banded(up,down,N):
# Copy the inputs and determine the size of the system 
# A = copy(Aa)
# v = copy(va)
    A=Return(N) 
    v=np.zeros(N) 
    v[0]=5
    v[1]=5
    # Gaussian elimination
    for m in range(N):
# Normalization factor
        div = A[up,m]
        # Update the vector first
        v[m] /= div
        for k in range(1,down+1):
            if m+k<N:
                v[m+k] -= A[up+k,m]*v[m]
# Now normalize the pivot row of A and subtract from lower ones
        for i in range(up): 
            j = m + up - i
            if j<N:
                A[i,j] /= div
                for k in range(1,down+1): 
                    A[i+k,j] -= A[up+k,m]*A[i,j]
    # Backsubstitution
    for m in range(N-2,-1,-1):
        for i in range(up):
            j = m + up - i 
            if j<N:
                v[m] -= A[i,j]*v[j]
    return v

print('when N=5',Return(5))
print('when N=6',Return(6))
print('when N=5',banded(2,2,5))
print('when N=6',banded(2,2,6))
```

It shows the error of /var/folders/7m/89pphx995jq8vjd_gzjwcjmh0000gn/T/ipykernel_748/1707559702.py:33: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
v[m] /= div
/var/folders/7m/89pphx995jq8vjd_gzjwcjmh0000gn/T/ipykernel_748/1707559702.py:49: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
v[m] -= A[i,j]*v[j]

```
import numpy as np # code 2
import time as time
def Return(N):
    A=np.zeros((N,N))
    v=np.zeros(N)
    v[0]=5
    v[1]=5
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if j==i:
                A[i,j]=4
            else:
                if j>i+2:
                    A[i,j]=0
                else:
                    A[i,j]=-1
    for i in range (2,N,+1):
        for j in range(0,i-2):
            A[i,j]=0
    A[N-1,N-1]=3
    A[0,0]=3 
    return A
def banded(N,up,down):
    t0=time.time() 
    A=np.copy(Return(N))
# Copy the inputs and determine the size of the system # A = copy(Aa)
# v = copy(va)
    v=np.zeros(N)
    v[0]=5
    v[1]=5
# Gaussian elimination
    for m in range(N):
# Normalization factor
        div = A[up,m]
        # Update the vector first
        v[m] /= div
        for k in range(1,down+1):
            if m+k<N:
                v[m+k] -= A[up+k,m]*v[m]
# Now normalize the pivot row of A and subtract from lower ones
        for i in range(up):
            j = m + up - i
            if j<N:
                A[i,j] /= div
                for k in range(1,down+1):
                    A[i+k,j] -= A[up+k,m]*A[i,j]
    # Backsubstitution
    for m in range(N-2,-1,-1): 
        for i in range(up):
            j = m + up - i 
            if j<N:
                v[m] -= A[i,j]*v[j]
    t1=time.time()-t0
    print('The time taken to do the calculation by banded function is:', t1)
    return v
def linalg(N): 
    t0=time.time()
    A=Return(N)
    w=np.zeros(N)
    w[0]=5
    w[1]=5
    ans=np.linalg.solve(A,w)
    print(ans)
    t1=time.time()-t0
    print('The required time to do the calculations by linalg is:', t1)
    
print(banded(1000,2,2))
print(linalg(1000))
```

It shows the similar error as well.

/var/folders/7m/89pphx995jq8vjd_gzjwcjmh0000gn/T/ipykernel_1618/2720557356.py:36: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
v[m] /= div
/var/folders/7m/89pphx995jq8vjd_gzjwcjmh0000gn/T/ipykernel_1618/2720557356.py:44: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
A[i,j] /= div

Plz help me,I don't know how to solve it although they run.

Answer (score 0):

All elements with index i, j at Array A equal to 0 when j > i+2. For example A[0, 3], A[1,4] etc.

In the meantime, div = A[up,m].

So when m > up +2, div will equal 0. Then v[m] /= div will raise the error "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars v[m] /= div".

Similar reason for the second error.

Depending on your logic, there should be different solutions here. One quick way is to check whether div value first. If div ==0, skip running v[m] /= div